# Swift: No reaction from toolbar buttons

Tags: swift, uikit

Screen below has the toolbar with two buttons. They have handlers. Handlers are not fired from buttons. I try to assign the handler to the red button and it works. I need help to find mistake

[image]

Here is my code below:

```
let toolbar: UIToolbar = {
    let tb = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10))
    tb.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(choosen))
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(cancelSelection))
    tb.items = [doneButton, cancelButton]
    tb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return tb
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let but = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
    but.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancelSelection), for: .touchUpInside)
    but.backgroundColor = .red
    self.view.addSubview(but)
    self.view.obscure()

    weightPicker.addSubview(toolbar)

    toolbar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: weightPicker.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    toolbar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: weightPicker.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    toolbar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    toolbar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: weightPicker.topAnchor).isActive = true

    self.view.addSubview(weightPicker)
    weightPicker.delegate = self
    weightPicker.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    weightPicker.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    weightPicker.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
    weightPicker.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

    @objc func choosen() {

    print(123)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@objc func cancelSelection() {

    print(123)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget to add ``@objc func choosen()`` and ``@objc func cancelSelection()``?

Comment: Sure. Compilator fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like sth goes wrong when you add an UIToolbar to the UIPickerView. You could add some container view instead:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let containerView = UIView()
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    weightPicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.addSubview(toolbar)
    containerView.addSubview(weightPicker)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
        toolbar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
        toolbar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
        toolbar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
        toolbar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),
        weightPicker.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: toolbar.bottomAnchor),
        weightPicker.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
        weightPicker.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
        weightPicker.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor)
    ])
}
```

Comment: It seems it is not possible to add toolbar just to view - compiler will fire error

Comment: What error did you receive? I've tested this on Xcode 9.0 and it's working.

Comment: I found other solution. I have created view and put buttons on it. Then I put this view on top of picker. I have doubts that your solution works as I understand that toolbar should link to texfield. Could you send me leonif1@gmail.com ? I will check. Thank you;)

Comment: Here you have [link](https://gist.github.com/TomaszPietrowski/2b2622f9ab4b5cf8c46fa80d40cca080) to gist. Just add it to playground to test.

Comment: you are best!!! I changed according to my case and it works. Why can I not add a toolbar on self.view and use it as a container?

Comment: I assume that it's possible but generally, UIToolbar is used to display UIBarButtonItems. You could try to customize toolbar's appearance but I'm not sure if it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

hi in you action try to add the name of your controller class before the name of the fuction  `#selector('here'.cancelSelection)` or do this `#selector(self.cancelSelection)`

Comment: weird .. i have a question  when you create your buttons and add them to your toolbar in viewDidLoad  there is no problem right ?

Answer (score 0):

try to use lazy i think the problem it's because your using self

```
lazy var toolbar: UIToolbar = {
let tb = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10))
tb.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.choosen))
let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(self.cancelSelection))
tb.items = [doneButton, cancelButton]
tb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
return tb}()
```

Comment: I have tried. No, react :(. I think that toolbar doesn't give access to buttons, however, I don't know how to check it